# Why is my WPF application slow on certain systems

Tags: .net, wpf, performance

I have problems with the performance of the UI of my WPF application on certain systems. On my developer system it performs just fine,  on certain other systems however the performance is really bad. The problem occurs e.g. when moving splitters, resizing FlowDocuments or hovering over buttons.

The performance difference is not directly related to the obvious ‘specs’ of the computer. The application performs OK on a netbook (Intel Atom N550,  1GB RAM, Windows performance index: 2.0), but not on a desktop computer (I7 2600, 8GB Ram, ATI Radeon HD 5700,  Windows performance index: 7.4). Both systems are running Windows 7.
The application is build with .NET 4.0. I have tried to force software rendering using RenderOptions.ProcessRenderMode = RenderMode.SoftwareOnly. This however makes no difference at all.

What is causing this problem? How can I fix it?

Comment: Two questions, firstly and easy to overlook, are the drivers for the slow pc from ATI or using stock windows 7 drivers that 'just work'? and second, are you using any custom or 3rd party UI controls?

Comment: The problem could be in a specific version of display drivers and driver vendor as well

Comment: Which editions of Windows 7 you have on these machines? I've experienced some WPF performance issues on Windows 7 Ultimate and it's gone after installing the Windows 7 Enterprise on same machine.

Comment: Regarding drivers: If I set RenderOptions.ProcessRenderMode = RenderMode.Software. Doesn't this mean that rendering is done by software and not by hardware? Can drivers than still be an issue?

Comment: I'm using 3rd party components from DevExpress.

Comment: I have experienced problems on Windows 7 Ultimate but also on Vista.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

This sounds like it might be the Wpf 4 bug we were stung by that affects apps with complex Wpf visual trees. It's discussed in this thread http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en/windowsaccessibilityandautomation/thread/6c4465e2-207c-4277-a67f-e0f55eff0110. It even affected the Workflow 4 designer in VS 2010 - see http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en/wfprerelease/thread/1f20c37f-1b9e-4b6d-904f-a6b518e4187a. According to that thread, there is a hotfix that you might want to try: http://support.microsoft.com/kb/2484841

You can get a good idea if this is the problem by attaching a debugger to your app when it is hung / stuttering and see if you see lots of UiAutomation InvalidateAutomationAncestors frames on the stack.

Comment: @FromTheMountain, Did you ever get this fixed? Did installing the hot fix work?  Please comment, I'm having the same issue.

Comment: Did updating to .NET 4.5 fix the issue?

Comment: @RayL - I am using 4.5 and I am having this issue still. I am also unable to install KB2484841. I would wager that has been rolled into later dll version that I already have. But like I said, I am still experiencing issues with the automation on my controls with complex visual trees.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe a x64 vs. x86 problem?  Setting the platform target to Any CPU.

Comment: I thought about this too. I was indeed set to x86. Unfortunately setting it to Any CPU did not fix the problem.

Comment: Some of our own apps have had problems with builds to "Any CPU" on x64 machines - did you try making a specific build for x64 ?